# --help gets stuck in command line for fire module

Tags: python, bash, command-line-interface, zsh

I have this simple code for python fire and for some reason I get stuck anytime I use the --help flag.

```
import fire

def double(number):
    """A simple function."""
    return 2 * number

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fire.Fire(double)
```

when I run

```
$ pipenv run python3 ./scripts/test.py --help
```

I get the help but also CLI hangs and I have to ctrl + C to exit.

Comment: You don't seem to be using it the way the example does here: https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/introducing-python-fire-library-for.html Try creating a class

Comment: It doesn't matter, that doesn't work for me either.It seems like there is something with the fire lib or my bash.

Comment: Try running it directly instead of through pipenv

Comment: @rdas doesn't work either :(

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem today and I dug in Fire's source code to see how I could solve it.

If you have a look [here](https://github.com/google/python-fire/blob/master/fire/console/console_io.py), you'll see that, when displaying help, Fire uses a concept of "pager". Either its own one or one specified through the PAGER environment variable. If you insert the following statement at the beginning of your script:

```
os.environ["PAGER"] = "cat"
```

you won't have to do a CTRL+C or :q anymore. Kind of a ugly workaround, but enough for me for the time being.